# springboot config externalization with different file name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am learning spring boot config externalization. I would like my application to read configuration from any external file (`/Users/<userid>/application.properties`).

I created spring-web project, and added `spring.config.location=${user.home}` entry to `src/main/resource/application.properties`

`testConfig` is the configuration property name I am trying to access via below code in my Controller class.

```java
 @Value("${testConfig})
 private String configValue;
```

I have given different values for `testConfig` in different places.

`testConfig=InsideJar` in `src/main/resources/application.properties` file.
`testConfig=ApplicationRoot` in project root directory `application.properties` file.
`testConfig=homeDir` in user home directory `/User/<userid>/application.properties` file.

How I ran the app and what is the result?

```
1. From different directory than project root
```

> **Command**: `java -jar ../Downloads/first-springboot-app/target/first-springboot-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   -Dspring.config.location=file:/User/${LOGNAME}/application.properties`
>       **Result**:`InsideJar`
>   ***Expected result*** : `homeDir`

.

```
2. From Project root directory
```

> **Command**: `java -jar target/first-springboot-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dspring.config.location=file:/Users/${LOGNAME}/application.properties`
>
> **Result**:`applicationRootDir`***Expected result*** : `homeDir`

```
3. Added spring.config.name=application
4. Added spring.config.name=application.properties
```

> Both of the above (3,4) gave same result .
>   **Result**:`applicationRootDir` ***Expected result*** : `homeDir`.

I already went through below links and other blogs .
[Springboot doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config)
[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635163/spring-boot-externalizing-properties-not-working), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32732784/spring-boot-externalize-config-properties).

**Question/Problem** : Why value (`homeDir`) is not fetched from `Users/<userid>/application.properties` ?
Any help would highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: I want to get `homeDir` as the result rather than other results.

Comment: I have couple of question here, 1) `in project root directory` which is `src ? 2) where are passing the value for this `${LOGNAME}` placeholder ? @new_programmer

Comment: @Deadpool: 
1. Root directory outside `src` folder.
2. ${LOGNAME} is to replace with userID. so that the path form to `/User/<userId>` (which is the directory where my `application.properties` reside)

Comment: Which spring boot version are you using, @new_programmer ?

Comment: @UroshT. - I am using `2.2.0` version.

Answer (score 0):

This should definitely work as expected, even without adding the `spring.config.name`.

I have ran a simple spring application with only `web` dependency from start.spring.io and added `-Dspring.config.location=file:/Users/my-user/application.properties`. Works as expected.

I then tested again with `-Dspring.config.location=file:/Users/${MY_USER}/application.properties` and declared `MY_USER=my-user`, which also worked. I did this to test that the an environment variable is also read from the path itself.

That being said, you are having an issue with the config and are probably missing some small setting. I have posted my code [here](https://github.com/urosht/so58468109) so feel free to check it out and compare it with yours.

Hope that helps,

Cheers